# Calculate Average Value for every N minutes

Tags: python-3.x, csv, average

My Logfile (Logfile.csv) looks like this:

```
2016-05-17 08:25    13.9    41.6
2016-05-17 08:26    13.9    41.6
2016-05-17 08:27    13.9    41.6
2016-05-17 08:28    13.9    41.7
2016-05-17 08:29    13.9    41.6
2016-05-17 08:30    13.9    41.6
```

1st row is Timestamp
2nd row is Temperature
3rd row is Humidity

How can I iterate over the lines so that I can calculate mean values for temperature and humidity for every N minutes.

```
f = open("Logfile.csv","r")
f_reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t",dialect='excel-tab')
for row in f_reader:
        stringRowDate = row[0]
        Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(stringRowDate,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        floatTemp = float(row[1])
        floatHum = float(row[2])
        ... group N minutes and calculate mean values for floatTemp and floatHum
```

I know that pandas would probably be a good option but I would prefer a csv related approach

Here's what I ended up with:

```
import csv
from datetime import timedelta
import datetime

last_time = None
temperatures = []
humidities = []

f = open("DataLogger.csv", "r+")
f_reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t",dialect='excel-tab')
for row in f_reader:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    if last_time is None:
        last_time = current_time
    temperatures.append(float(row[1]))
    humidities.append(float(row[2]))
    if (current_time - last_time) > datetime.timedelta(minutes=10):
        with open('/DataLoggerAVE.csv', 'a') as f:
        x = csv.writer(f,dialect='excel-tab')
        avetemp=temperature=sum(temperatures) / len(temperatures)
        avehumidity=sum(humidities) / len(humidities)
        x.writerow([current_time, avetemp, avehumidity])
        last_time = current_time
        temperatures = []
        humidities = []
```

I get the mean values for each time interval I define with the timedelta for humidity and temperatures
thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. use a timedelta to compare the time and a list to keep values. Then calculate the average like this: `sum(values) / len(values)`

Here is some example:

But keep in mind, that this approach does not handle remaining data, and expects the input sorted by date.

```
import csv
import datetime

f_reader = csv.reader('''
2016-05-17 08:25\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:26\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:27\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:28\t13.9\t41.7
2016-05-17 08:29\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:30\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:31\t13.8\t41.5
2016-05-17 08:32\t13.7\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:33\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:34\t13.9\t41.7
2016-05-17 08:35\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:40\t13.9\t41.6
2016-05-17 08:34\t13.9\t41.8
    '''.strip().splitlines(), delimiter='\t', dialect='excel-tab')

last_time = None  # keep track of the time
temperatures = []
humidities = []

for row in f_reader:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    print(current_time)

    if last_time is None:
        last_time = current_time

    temperatures.append(float(row[1]))
    humidities.append(float(row[2]))

    if (current_time - last_time) > datetime.timedelta(minutes=3):
        print('''
averages from '{last}' to '{curr}'
    temperature:    {temperature:06.3f}
    humidity:       {humidity:06.3f}
        '''.format(
            last=last_time, curr=current_time,
            temperature=sum(temperatures) / len(temperatures),
            humidity=sum(humidities) / len(humidities),
        ).lstrip())

        last_time = current_time
        temperatures = []
        humidities = []
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, pretty much what I was looking for, could not get my head around how to iterate in certain steps over the rows, sorry if my question seemed lazy